# Angular4 + Sass - Module build failed:

Tags: angular, sass

I'm setting up new project. I need help with sass implementation in Angular4. I have no idea why I keep getting this error.

.html .sass
[image]

console error
[image]

I have sass installed on my computer, and default styleExt was set to sass when creating project through cmd

I can't find any explanaion on the internet neither on stack overflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a valid Sass syntax (the use of braces `{}`). Did you intend to use Scss instead? (both are usually pronounced the same way). The above syntax is valid for Scss.

You can either change the default `styleExt` to `scss` (and rename your styles related files to end in `.scss` or remove the braces `{}` from the styles file shown.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution to this problem in the same time when you posted your answer actuallly. This was quite confusing to me that sass has two different types of syntax. I hope your answer will help other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, `Invalid CSS after .navigation`

This is a valid sass:

```
.navigation
   border-color: red
```

What you're trying to do is SCSS. Change your styleExt to scss on `.angular-cli.json`